# Is there a website/service that corrects Chinese essays?

Tags: learning, resources

Recently, I've gotten into the habit of writing in a Chinese diary each night. However, I'd be disappointed if I kept on making mistakes and instead of correcting them, reinforcing them through the diary. Does anyone know of any services that correct Chinese essays?

Comment: I believe a forum helps, since humans always do better than machine in that part. But it's your diary, a private stuff.
Do you have a skype account? You can practice Chinese over skype for free. As I know, a lot of Chinese use skype to chat with foreigners online(for language exchanging).

Comment: Huh, ya see I'd love to have a service where I could send in an essay and have it corrected. Skype is awesome! But I'm afraid it doesn't work that well for essay correction

Comment: OK. Maybe I can help you with that if you mean it.(Oh that is out of your question here :D)

Comment: Sean C. If you are interested - I would love the help! You've already been so helful - I know you are a great help when it comes to Chinese!

Comment: I don't know if it's ok to post email here. Or you should visit my profile to check it.

Comment: I don't think it's on there - send me an email at turban@college.harvard.edu if you get the chance!

Comment: Talk to native speakers in Chinese website is a effective way , but I don't think you can access Chinese website cause the GWF...

Answer (score 1):

Stephen.
I am a Chinese and interested in your Chinese essays..
Could you POST them or one to me , if i can do anything for help , i will repeat to you .
you can just post it below , or this is my email : hunter.v.wang@gmail.com

```
Looking forward to your essays..
```

[You must have 50 reputation to comment]

so , i leave the comment in answer ,sorry;

Comment: You can quickly gain enough reputation to comment by leaving a valid answer on any number of questions. I have plenty of those on my profile, which need additional answers.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if there is any, but, I can't find one. Maybe you can post your essay here at [**Stack Exchange**](http://chinese.stackexchange.com) and ask for corrections. :)

Comment: I don't think that stack exchange is the right forum for full essay correction. We  should be looking for single answers that can help others out in the future.